# Invite Friends message for App to User Notifications in Facebook

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I would like to send Facebook app requests to my friends to try my app. But when user receives the notification, the message looks like '**Invited you to play App**'. But I need the message like '**Invited you to try App**'. I mentioned the code below,

```
FB.ui({
method: 'apprequests',
message: 'Welcome!!!',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

App Requests are for games only (they are also called "Game Requests"), there is no way to change that message.

For Apps, you should use the [Send Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog) instead.

Comment: Is any other way to send the app request?? For my use case??

Comment: i just updated my answer, the send dialog is usually the way to go for apps